# Alphabetical ordering of a utf8_bin table with Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, utf-8, sql-order-by, collation

I store a table in MySQL with collation utf8_bin. I want to select all names ordered alphabetically using Codeigniter's [active record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) tools but the code below sorts all words starting by a capital letter first, then the non-capitalised ones (they are not capitalised for a reason).

```
$this->db->select('name')
    ->from('partners')
    ->order_by('name', 'asc')
    ->get()
    ->result();
```

I read that using `ORDER BY name COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` would make the sort case insensitive without having to change my table collation. Is there a way to do that with Codeigniter? This is likely to be required for many tables and I'd like to avoid using `LOWER(name)` in my query as an extra column to order by.

Comment: if you change your collation on the fly in your query it , decreases your performance very much. if it is possible change your collation permanently.

Comment: Does using lower(name) in the order by decrease performance a lot?

Comment: you must benchmark it, but I think so.

Comment: Well since the tables where I need this will have a max of 30 rows, the performance hit is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

Using `$this->db->order_by('lower(name)', 'asc')` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
order by cast(name as char) asc, binary name desc
```

Comment: Using this gave an "error in my SQL syntax". However using $this->db->order_by('lower(name)', 'asc') worked.

Comment: $this->db->order_by('cast(name as char) asc, binary name desc') , does not work?

Comment: no because it escapes binary so the query becomes ORDER BY cast(name as char) asc, 'binary' name desc